# WP7 - Image Click Event?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to assign a click event to images?  I would like to assign events to the delete and search buttons inside of my listbox that displays my data.  Is there a way to do this using the image control or do I have to create a style in BLEND for a button?

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lbPills" ItemsSource="{Binding pillItemsCollection}" SelectionChanged="lbPills_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0">*</TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="-2,-13,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Image Source="Images/delete.png" Margin="10,0"/>
                        <Image Source="Images/search.png" Margin="10,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the gesture listener to detect tap (click) events. A walkthrough here.

[WP7 Tip of the Day: Silverlight Toolkit: Gestures](http://www.geekchamp.com/news/wp7-tip-of-the-day-silverlight-toolkit-gestures)

Alternatively, you can place your image into a Button control and retemplate it in blend to have the appearance you want.

Comment: Is there a way to add an ID or the Index Value to the image using Gestures so I can tell which item in the collection was selected when the button was clicked?

Comment: /All - The Gestures worked great!  I'm using the SelectionChanged="lbPills_SelectionChanged" to figure out which item in the collection was clicked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Linked tutorial doesn't exist.

Answer (score 13):

To my knowledge there are no listeners on the Image itself for click and gesture events (they will have to be attached via Gestures as previously mentioned). One way to approach this is to re-template the button:

```
        <Button>
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/delete.png" Margin="10,0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

In setting the template on the button you will override the default template used by the phone (which has the extra padding, thick border, etc.). Using this method will allow you to tie into the button click event.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, I tried your answer for another button I was using where I wanted to contain an image and it worked great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `ManipulationCompleted` event (which is **any** tap, double-tap, swipe, caress or fondle) to your image(s). So:

`<Image Source="Images/delete.png" Margin="10,0"/>` becomes `<Image x:Name="ImageDelete" ManipulationCompleted="ImageDelete_ManipulationCompleted" Source="Images/delete.png" Margin="10,0"/>`. Then in the `ImageDelete_ManipulationCompleted` handler, track from whence it came in from the `sender` and do your thing.

If you want to only track a swipe instead of a tap, just do an if statement on the `e.IsInertial` from `ManipulationCompletedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `ListBox` is not in a `Panorama` control, then you could just handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the list box and then display the Delete and Search options in an `ApplicationBar` for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp. It replaces the tab or click on the device like you have click event on pc with mouse. It works in my app. Just try this and you will be happy, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way for me (Making Padding="-10" removed the button border and padding inside the button)

```
<Button x:Name="Channells" Click="Thumb_Click" Padding="-10" >
      <Image 
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Source="Assets/Images/thumb2.jpg"/>
</Button>
```

*.cs

```
 void Thumb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Thumb Clicked");
    }
```